# Running same Cucumber Features on different machines concurrently using parallel_tests gem

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, capybara, parallel-testing

Running same Cucumber Features on different machines concurrently using parallel_tests gem

I'm trying to figure out how to use the parallel_tests gem to run the EXACT SAME Cucumber Features on a variety of different machines concurrently.

Currently I have them running on different machines but the SAME features do not execute, it just splits up the features and runs different features on different machines.

More clarification on what I want to do:

```
MACHINE 1 (Win 7) - EXECUTE SAME FEATURES CONCURRENTLY
MACHINE 2 (Win 8) - EXECUTE SAME FEATURES CONCURRENTLY
MACHINE 3 (Mac OS X) - EXECUTE SAME FEATURES CONCURRENTLY
...
```

Also my architecture is:

Cucumber -> Capybara -> Selenium Webdriver -> Selenium Grid

parallel_tests gem: https://github.com/grosser/parallel_tests

Comment: In my understanding the propose of parallel_tests is to run DIFFERENT features in different machines to shorten the waiting for run the whole suite. What do you want really to do?

Comment: Because if you want to run the whole suite in each computer then run that independently but at the same time. Please clarify your propose.

Comment: I want to run the SAME features on multiple machines (OSs/browsers) to cover all the supported environments...

Answer (score 0):

The parallel_tests gem is really purposed to parallellism, not executing multiple platforms.

You may find the following useful:
[Sauce Gem 30 rake tasks](https://github.com/saucelabs/sauce_ruby/wiki/Concurrent-Testing#sauce-gem-30-rake-tasks)

"The Sauce integration is currently targeted at RSpec and Cucumber, running on a local server you can spin up multiple copies of. It runs a copy of each test for each platform, and divides them up across all the concurrency available to your Sauce Labs account by default"

Hope it helps, I haven't used it myself yet.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the clarification. To accomplish testing your app for all the supported environments (OSs/browsers) you can use something as [Selenium Grid](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/Grid2) here is an example [Selenium RC: Run tests in multiple browsers automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213430/selenium-rc-run-tests-in-multiple-browsers-automatically).

TestingBot is a service that use this: http://blog.testingbot.com/2012/02/19/selenium-cucumber-capybara

Other approach is described here: http://altoros.github.io/2013/running-capybara-tests-in-remote-browsers/

http://paauspaani.blogspot.mx/2013/05/running-tests-remotely-using-selenium.html

There is also a presentation: http://www.slideshare.net/martinkleppmann/crossbrowser-testing-in-the-real-world

Also this could help you [Has anyone figured out a way to run the same cucumber scenario on multiple browsers/web drivers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4384346/has-anyone-figured-out-a-way-to-run-the-same-cucumber-scenario-on-multiple-brows?rq=1)

Hopefully this will give you some clues.

Answer (score 0):

I am confused by this statement of yours:

> Currently I have them running on different machines but the SAME
>   features do not execute, it just splits up the features and runs
>   different features on different machines.

parallel_tests is used for splitting up tests and running them on multiple cores, not on a distributed environment of multiple machines. It can group tests to be run on a distributed environment using the `--only-group` flag, but it doesn't actually run tests on a distributed environment. So you have to do some lifting yourself to get the tests running on a distributed environment. You could run all of your tests on multiple machines like so:

1. Use [net-ssh](https://github.com/net-ssh/net-ssh) to ssh into each one of your boxes.
2. Use each ssh session to run your parallel_tests script (which should break the tests up and run them in parallel on the *current* box -- just don't use the `--only-group` option [as described here](https://github.com/grosser/parallel_tests/wiki/Distributed-Parallel-Tests-and-Travis-Support))